# How could I stop all the functions in the background.html?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey everyone!
I am new in chrome extension developing, and in my extension, I have a pop up window to show something when it's running, and if the window is closed, I want the whole extension to stop running, but some functions in the background.html are still running, so how could I stop all the functions?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you have some cronjob on a `setTimeout()`, or want to interrupt javascript code in the middle of executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your popup,

```
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
bkg.location.reload()
```

That will stop everything and reload the background page. If you want to control the reloading state, you can have a function in the background page that you call `bkg.callSomeFunction()`